# Migrating from JIRA to Rally

Tags: migration, jira, rally, scrum

We use Scrum, or we think we are using Scrum!  We have been using JIRA for our user stories and tasks.  The leadership decided to discontinue JIRA and move to Rally.  Don't ask me why!!

Is there a way to migrate our user stories and tasks from JIRA to Rally?

Manually moving them is going to be a gargantuan task!

Comment: Interesting that I am looking for the opposite thing, as I need to redo a less fortunate move from JIRA to Rally now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rally has a connector for Jira:

[For JIRA 5.2 or greater](http://help.rallydev.com/jira-5-installation-user-guide)

[For JIRA 4.0 - 4.4](http://help.rallydev.com/jira-installation-user-guide)

Or if you export your data from Jira to Excel, you may import it to Rally using [Rally Excel plugin](http://help.rallydev.com/rally-add-excel-installation-user-guide)

Contact Rally support for more information.

Comment: Rally has a Jira connector that references Jira bug reports and not the user stories.  So that didn't help.  I tried exporting data to xml and import it, but that didn't work well either.  I guess I will have to contact Rally support.

Comment: The list of supported artifact types includes user stories: (Defect, Story, TestCase). See: http://help.rallydev.com/jira-5-installation-user-guide